# How to accept other type of files for ocr processing?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

i want to know how to accept other type of files for ocr processing, currently i only can accept the img file like jpg,png but not the pdf. Also, i want to show the progress bar when the tesseract is extracting the text. Anyone gonna guide me, thx?

Here my code:

```
   private void btOCR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                //var img = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
                var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(openFileDialog.FileName);
                var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);
                var page = ocr.Process(img);
                txtResult.Text = page.GetText() + page.GetMeanConfidence();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: PDF files aren't images in the same way that JPG and PNGs are, they're documents which can contain images, so first you'd need to write code to extract the images from the PDF and then process them in a similar way to the way you already are.

Comment: A PDF might actually contain the text, which would be better than OCR.  Or it might be image based.  Either way you'll want to use a PDF library to pull out the contents.  Or find a quick and dirty way to convert the PDF to an image like using a print driver.